# CLIPS: How to evaluate multifield values as integers

Tags: clips, expert-system

I'm struggling to evaluate properly the integer values of a multifield value.

Ultimately what I need is to pattern-match a multislot containing only integers and be able to tell if the "list" is in ascending order.

What I have so far:

```
(defclass status 
    (is-a USER)
    (role concrete)
    (pattern-match reactive)
    (multislot numbers
        (create-accessor write)
        (type INTEGER) 
        (range 1 ?VARIABLE) 
        (default 1)
     )
)

(defrule asc
    ?st <- (object (is-a status) (numbers $?n))
    (test (> (length ?n) 2))
    (test (< (first$ ?n) (rest$ ?n)))
=> 
    (printout t "List " ?n " is ascending" crlf)
)

(make-instance of status (numbers 1 2 3))
```

I understand that probably that's not the way to expand a multislot and populate arguments for (<) but I can't seem to find the right way.
And even if the arguments expanded properly, it still says that it requires an integer argument, but

```
(first$ ?n)
```

does not evaluate to an integer.

My question is:
How can I take a value of a list of values and "parse" it as an integer?
Second of all, how can I expand these values to make them arguments of (<) and tell if the list is in ascending order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nth$ function to retrieve a single value from a multifield. For the first value, you'd use (nth$ 1 ?n). In your rule, however, all you need to do is use the expand$ function to splice the value of the numbers slot into the argument list of the < function.

```
CLIPS> 
(defclass status 
   (is-a USER)
   (multislot numbers))
CLIPS> 
(defrule asc
   (object (is-a status) (numbers $?n))
   (test (> (length ?n) 1))
   (test (< (expand$ ?n)))
   => 
   (printout t "List " ?n " is ascending" crlf))
CLIPS> (make-instance of status (numbers 1 2 3))
[gen1]
CLIPS> (make-instance of status (numbers 2 3 1 4))
[gen2]
CLIPS> (run)
List (1 2 3) is ascending
CLIPS>
```